# Get a specific value of a XML type file with REGEX

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have been trying alot of ways with REGEX, but I can' get one to work.
I have a file with alot of xml-type data... and i need to retreive this one:

A-bunch-of-number

Tried many different ways to get it to work but I didn't get anything to work.. just return a blank anwser

Last code I tried:

```
        Dim loc As String = "C:\Users\David\Documents\getconfig.php"
    Dim w As New System.IO.StreamReader(loc)
    Dim test As String = w.ReadToEnd
    Dim r As New Regex("<rss-sync-time>"".*""</<rss-sync-time>")
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(test)
```

Comment: have you tried DOM? by the way, you need to show us, what kinda of code you're trying to parse

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim r As New Regex("<rss-sync-time>"".*?""</<rss-sync-time>", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```